# MAUI: how to use Border StrokeShape property to draw a perfect circle?

Tags: maui

My last attempt was this:

```
                        <Border Stroke="#649B33"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                StrokeShape="Ellipse 30, 30"
                                Padding="8"
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="1" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        </Border>
```

Documentation is very very poor regarding `StrokeShape` property, so I am trying to guess the correct way, but I have actually spent too much time and nothing works.

Can you show me how to use `StrokeShape` property to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me

```
    <Border Stroke="#649B33"
            StrokeThickness="10"
            StrokeShape="Ellipse 40, 40"
            Padding="8"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
               WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"
               Text="1" FontAttributes="Bold" />
    </Border>
```

I think the key is setting the same width and height values for the label so that it is square